# Is there value to my misprinted Magic card?

Tags: magic-the-gathering, pricing

I have a magic card with a unique misprint. The Red Mana symbol in the card text is in grey-scale print, but the rest of the card is in full, correct color, including the Red Mana symbol in the card's cost.

I looked for misprint values, and there is a market for it, but I couldn't find anything on this type of misprint.

Is this a valuable card, and where should I look at for selling it?

Comment: Could you confirm the name of the card that you believe is misprinted?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Is the card from a set in the 8th Edition - Fifth Dawn range? If yes then this is ***not*** a misprint.

(if no, then that is an interesting find indeed...)

This was when the Magic card frame was changed and it was decided to print "mana symbols in running text in black-and-white instead of color" for a number of reasons. This decision has since been reversed.

This question was [asked and answered on Ask Wizards in May of 2003](http://magic.wizards.com/en/articles/archive/ask-wizards-may-2003-2003-05-01). See the May 20, 2003 question from Philip, answered by Randy Buehler.

> **May 20, 2003**
>
> **Q:** "I saw one of the Two-Headed Dragon promo cards that was given away
> at E3 last week. What's up with the red mana symbol in the text box?
> It looks black or gray instead of red."
> --Philip R
>
> **A:** From Randy Buehler, Director of Magic R&D:
>
> "You're right -- the red
> mana symbol that appears in the 'firebreathing' ability in the text
> box on Two-Headed Dragon is black text, and it will be the same on the
> actual Eighth Edition cards. **"We looked at all aspects of our printing
> process when we were putting together the new card frames and it
> turned out to be much simpler if we did the mana symbols in running
> text in black-and-white instead of color.** We've had problems with them
> in the past, especially on foil cards, and by changing them to black
> text we will be able to minimize these mistakes. R&D was initially
> concerned that they would be harder to read and gameplay would be
> affected by this change, so we had some playtest cards printed up and
> tested with them in our Future Future League. After playing with them,
> we realized that you never really notice the difference. In fact,
> since the text box itself is colored, it tricks your eye into seeing
> the symbol as colored too. Based on this playtesting, we concluded
> that the advantages of making our printing process more efficient and
> subject to fewer errors outweighed the drawback of making the cards
> slightly less pretty and so we made the change. (Note that only mana
> symbols that appear in text in text boxes are affected by this change
> -- mana costs in the upper right and basic lands will stay the same.)"

Comment: [Picture of the card referenced by the quoted passage](http://magiccards.info/8e/en/229.html). The OP could similarly look up their card on magiccard.info to determine if it's actually a misprint or not.